# extract some data from all sheet et copy in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, find, copy, worksheet

[sheet client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq1Nk.png) [capture erreur code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0J1k.png)

i need to extract the text in the  cells names "_mailclient" when i can find ref previously enter.
the code need to :
-find in all sheet the reference, put in the messge box
-if he find the the word, he extrait the cells "_mailclient" of the sheet with the ref and put him in another sheet and pass to the next sheet
-if not he pass to the next sheet.
-repet the code for evely sheet.
Thanks for your time

```
Sub recherche_mail()

Dim feuille As Worksheet
Dim valeurtrouve As Range
Dim recherche As String
Dim nomclient As String

'Intéger reference for FIND 
recherche = InputBox("Pour quel réparation doit je extraire les clients ?", "référence de la 
réparation")

'for every sheet in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each feuille In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

'affect the variable to valeurtrouve
Set valeurtrouve = feuille.Range("C8:C10000").Find(recherche, , xlValues, xlWhole)

'if valeur trouve was find copy it 
If valeurtrouve.Value = recherche.Value Then

'and paste in another sheet
Sheets.Add.Name = "liste client"
Sheets("listeclient").Range("A1").Cells.Range("_mailclient").Copy
Range("A2").Select
End If
Next feuille

'if isn't find next sheet
If Not valeurtrouve Is Nothing Then Exit For
Next feuille

'if no more sheet exit and message box and sub 
If Not valeurtrouve Is Nothing Then
MsgBox (" la liste a été créer "), True
Else

'if no people was find message box and sub
MsgBox "Personne n'a cette rèf ... va falloir bosser un peu plus", vbInformation
End If

End Sub
```

I hope it's clear, i'm a begginer please be indulgent :')

Comment: Try show sample data in the worksheet, it is abit unclear why the code is not working based on your description. Probably when it should match the result

Comment: i put an image of erreur code. It said "recherche" is a qualifying wasn't correct. (it's probably not the only probleme)

Comment: No, i mean the image of your excel data....

Comment: Picture 1 : it is what you need ?

Comment: Ya, something like this, let me take a look, will work out for you, but I am abit busy now so may not be today. BTW, if you found the client name, which information you need to copy to `new sheet`? Address, mail and telehpone?

Comment: thanks for your time don't worry. if you have the time that was cool but it's not a priority !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your information, I have modified your code and allow add new sheet multiple times using same name, and if `new sheet` added then will display successful message :

```
Sub recherche_mail()

Dim feuille As Worksheet, newWb As Worksheet
Dim valeurtrouve
Dim recherche As String

Dim i As Long, colNum As Long
Dim searchResult As Boolean

'Intéger reference for FIND
recherche = InputBox("Pour quel réparation doit je extraire les clients ?", "référence de la réparation ")
searchResult = False

colNum = 1

'for every sheet in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each feuille In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'affect the variable to valeurtrouve
    valeurtrouve = feuille.Range("C8:C10")

If searchResult = True Then
        For i = LBound(valeurtrouve) To UBound(valeurtrouve)
        If InStr(CStr(valeurtrouve(i, 1)), recherche) > 0 Then
            feuille.Range("B1:B4").Copy newWb.Cells(1, colNum)
            colNum = colNum + 1
        End If
    Next
End If


If searchResult = False Then
    For i = LBound(valeurtrouve) To UBound(valeurtrouve)
        If InStr(CStr(valeurtrouve(i, 1)), recherche) > 0 Then
            Sheets.Add.Name = "liste client"
            Set newWb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("liste client")
            feuille.Range("B1:B4").Copy newWb.Cells(1, colNum)
            colNum = colNum + 1
            searchResult = True
            
        End If
    Next
End If

Next feuille


If searchResult = False Then
    MsgBox (" No record is found "), vbOKOnly
Else
    MsgBox "People found and new sheet created"
End If

End Sub
```

Let say if you key in `RVA` in the input box, new sheet will be added by copy `Range A1:B4' else nothing will happen, please try and adjust it for your need:

**Combine Sheet**

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very mutch,, it's almost that. I juste need to extract the mail of the client and put all those mail in juste  one sheet.

Comment: Try explain with image? Because you didnot mention this step, you want extact mail from all client event it is not match?

Comment: i have post an answer wish more explaination, said me if it's more clear for you; If not i will tray again.

Comment: I saw your new update, but I still don't understand where is the range `email` ? Or you are copy new sheet email to the master sheet call `Feuliclient`?

Comment: Or just copy entire sheet to the new?

Comment: the range email was the cell B3, i have just change the name. It's the information that i need to extract for all client with the same reference and put itogether in a new sheet

Comment: Different customer will have the same reference? How is the combine of all different customer in new sheet look like?

Comment: yes diffenret customer have the same reference, exemple a ref for a reparation. and this is that i integer with rehcerche. It's juste a liste off all adresse cells by cells. It's just for extract every adresse of all client witch the same reference.

Comment: I have edited the answer, you can try it again, but always delete the `combine sheet `before you rerun it. I will considered it as final version, any further improve should be done by you :)

Comment: thanks you so mutch for your time, i will see that and repare it.

Comment: Accept the answer if helping you :)

Comment: I have test it, and that works. I need juste some modification but it's nothing compare to your works.

Comment: Welcome, as long as you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Feuil client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9SOc.png)

- i need a message boxe to put the reference, i will search
- when the reference was enter, the code will see on one sheet if the reference was here:
  if yes : the copy it and paste it in a new sheet.
  if not he pass to the next one
- next sheet : same action.
  if he find something he copy it and past in the same sheet than the last step
  if not he pass to the next one
- at the end :
  if he have found something put a message boxe : sheet create
  if not :" no client found")